# Wordpress adding (wrong) image dimensions

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I hope someone here can help.

Since my site upgraded to WordPress 5.9.1 a few days back (maybe sooner: I don't check every day) I've had an infuriating problem with image dimensions.

Now, for instance, on a page of images of width 960px, which has displayed perfectly full-width for years (960px being the width of the page) they are now all automatically resized to 630px.

I inspected this in Chrome (Inspect > Elements) and the images have somewhere along the line acquired incorrect dimensions, which are not part of the code I have written -- e.g.

```
<img class="..." src="..." width="630" height="420">.
```

To be clear, width="630" height="420" are nothing to do with me: the image is not that size, nor the containing div, nor any other aspect of the page, which has shown the image at its true width of 960px for years.

My question is, how can I override these incorrect dimensions (which I'm guessing Wordpress is adding). They are causing problems all over my website. I am sure my site is far from watertight, but aside from coding the dimensions inline for every image, I cannot figure out a way to fix it.

In hope.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching for $content_width .
The image width was being limited by $content_width set to 640 in the functions.php file . if not able to find then try to override in function's.php file and check $content_width = 1200;